# Understanding well the definition of a Gaussian vector according to Le Gall's book.

Tags: probability, gaussian

I am reading the book "Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus", Jean-François Le Gall and I have a doubt regarding the Gaussian vector definition.

First, the enveiroment is $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a proability space and $E$ a $d$-dimensional Euclidean space with inner product. When he defines a Gaussian vector, he states that a "radom variable" $X$ is a Gaussian vector with values in $E$ if $\forall\, u \in E$, $<u, X>$ is a (real) Gaussian variable.

But what is the definition of the inner product $<u,X>$?

As far as I know, the inner product is only defined for elements of $E$:
$$<.,.> E \times E \to \mathbb{R}$$

How to correctly define the inner product between an element of $E$ and a "random variable" $X: \Omega \to E$?

Comment: $\omega \mapsto \langle u, X(\omega) \rangle$ is Gaussian?

Comment: In this case, I think ther is nothing random. $X(\omega)$ is a realization.

Comment: I meant that $Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, Y(\omega) := \langle u, X(\omega) \rangle$ is a Gaussian random variable.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Naturally, for this to have a certain distribution it needs to be random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a (somewhat weird) way of saying that a Gaussian vector is a random vector such that any linear combination of the components of the vector is (real) Gaussian. (This latter way is how Le Gall defines Gaussian vectors in his other book, *Measure Theory, Probability and Stochastic Processes*.)

**First way:**

If $\boldsymbol X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R^d$ is a random vector with values in $\mathbb R^d$, then it can be written as $\boldsymbol X = (X_1, \dots, X_d)$ where each component is a random variable into $\mathbb R$.

If $\boldsymbol \alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_d) \in \mathbb R^d$, then a linear combination of the components would be
$$
\alpha_1 X_1 + \dots + \alpha_d X_d,
$$
and this is formally a map
$$
(\alpha_1 X_1 + \dots + \alpha_d X_d) \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R, \quad \omega \mapsto \alpha_1 X_1(\omega) + \dots + \alpha_d X_d(\omega).
$$

So $\boldsymbol X$ is defined to be a Gaussian vector when $\alpha_1 X_1 + \dots + \alpha_d X_d$ is (real) Gaussian for any $\boldsymbol \alpha \in \mathbb R^d$.

**Second way:**

We still have $\boldsymbol X$ and $\boldsymbol \alpha$, and consider the map
$$
\langle \boldsymbol \alpha, \boldsymbol X \rangle \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R \quad \omega \mapsto \langle \boldsymbol \alpha, \boldsymbol X(\omega) \rangle = \alpha_1 X_1(\omega) + \dots + \alpha_d X_d(\omega).
$$

So $\boldsymbol X$ is defined to be a Gaussian vector when $\langle \boldsymbol \alpha, \boldsymbol X \rangle$ is (real) Gaussian for any $\boldsymbol \alpha \in \mathbb R^d$.

**Comparison of first and second way:**

Because for any $\boldsymbol \alpha = (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_d) \in \mathbb R^d$, $(\alpha_1 X_1 + \dots + \alpha_d X_d) \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$ and $\langle \boldsymbol \alpha, \boldsymbol X \rangle \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$ are the same map, there is no difference in the definitions.